# Add elements in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {title: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], avg1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], avg2: [2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 7]}
```

I want to add the items in lists "avg1" and "avg2" based on the items in list "title". The resultant dic will be:

```
dic = {title: ['a', 'b', 'c'], avg1: [6, 9, 13], avg2: [7, 11, 16]}
```

Comment: Why is this being down voted? This is a clear question.

Comment: Although I haven't down voted, I imagine it is because this reads a bit like a "please code this for me" question. It would be useful if the OP could explain a little more about where they are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you rethink about your data structure, the way you store the information is a bit awkward. Below can do what you want in pandas, but it's an awkward use of pandas (I mean the last line in particular)

```
import pandas as pd

>>> d = {title: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], avg1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], avg2: [2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 7]}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   avg1  avg2 title
   0     1     2     a
   1     2     2     a
   2     3     3     a
   3     4     4     b
   4     5     7     b
   5     6     9     c
   6     7     7     c
>>> g = df.groupby('title')

>>> g.avg1.apply(sum)
title
a         6
b         9
c        13
Name: avg2, dtype: int64

>>> g.avg2.apply(sum)
title
a         7
b        11
c        16
Name: avg2, dtype: int64

# An very awkward use of pandas
>>> dict(title=g.avg1.apply(sum).index.values.tolist(),
>>>      avg1=g.avg1.apply(sum).values.tolist(),
>>>      avg2=g.avg2.apply(sum).values.tolist())
{'avg1': [6, 9, 13], 'avg2': [7, 11, 16], 'title': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```